# Nextjs and Kubernetes - Separating build and runtime

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, argocd

I have been looking for a way to reduce cpu and memory allocation in my kubernetes pod for my nextjs app. Due to constraints, I need to run `next build` on first container launch, which requires significant memory and cpu, but once it's built, it doesn't need much at all.

I've tried init containers, but [according to the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#resources), the pod picks the highest values in the cpu and memory specification, and sets that for the entire pod. I'm using Argocd.

I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendation of things to look into, or, if they've faced this problem before, what steps they took to solve it.

Ideally I would like to segregate the allocation between the build and runtime phase. I thought maybe spinning up a container, building the app, then passing over the assets to the runtime container?

Comment: If you having CI/CD you can build you dev/uat/prod image on CI server and create new docker and push it to k8s cluster directly so this way there is no need to use the build command and adding artifacts into image will resolve issue

Comment: You should be able to `RUN next build` in your image's Dockerfile, rather than on first launch.  That would both reduce your memory requirements and startup time.  Would that approach work for you?

Comment: The issue is the environment variables are only available to the pod when it is launched, and with next.js you need them at build time as well as run time. The environment I'm building for isn't available in the ci pipeline.

Comment: I'm looking for solutions for passing env vars to Next.js in the pod as well. Any luck? The only thing i've come up with is to use Next.js runtime config to fetch env vars at runtime. The trade off though is that you no longer get automatic static optimization which is a huge con. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration

Comment: @Ryan Haven't come up with a solution i'm afraid. For now we're just eating the cost when a new deployment happens and the memory spikes (running yarn build && yarn start on container launch).